# Unable to import a function from file in same directory

Tags: go

I am following a tutorial and stuck on this. I also tried to go through official docs, but was unable to find out that's wrong.

Before posting here i found out that GOPATH also needs to be configured.

GOPATH: *A:\GO*

Path to utils folder: *A:\GO\fem-intro-to-go\05_toolkit\code\utils*

There are 2 files in utils, **math.go** and **add_test.go**.

**math.go**

```
package utils

import "fmt"

func printNum(num int) {
    fmt.Println("Current Number:", num)
}

// Add adds together multiple numbers
func Add(nums ...int) int {
    total := 0
    for _, v := range nums {
        printNum(v)
        total += v
    }
    return total
}
```

**add_test.go**

```
package utils

import "testing"

func TestAdd(t *testing.T) {
    expected := 4
    actual := Add(2, 2)

    if actual != expected {
        t.Errorf("Add function does not add up: Expected: %d, Actual: %d", expected, actual)
    }
}
```

VS code is giving an error in add_test.go: **undeclared name: Add**

Full Description of error:

```json
{
    "resource": "/a:/GO/fem-intro-to-go/05_toolkit/code/utils/add_test.go",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
    "code": {
        "value": "UndeclaredName",
        "target": {
            "$mid": 1,
            "external": "https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternal?utm_source%3Dgopls#UndeclaredName",
            "path": "/golang.org/x/tools/internal/typesinternal",
            "scheme": "https",
            "authority": "pkg.go.dev",
            "query": "utm_source=gopls",
            "fragment": "UndeclaredName"
        }
    },
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "undeclared name: Add",
    "source": "compiler",
    "startLineNumber": 9,
    "startColumn": 12,
    "endLineNumber": 9,
    "endColumn": 15
}
```

Comment: Show us the contents of your `go.mod` file and the directory structure of the project.

Comment: Also try to run/test the code outside of VS, using your terminal and directly invoking the `go` tool. If it works there then the problem is in your VS setup. If it doesn't work there then the problem is in your module setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any problems with your code when building it using go 1.16.6.  If I start a new go project:

```
mkdir example
cd example
go mod init example
```

Then place your code in the `utils/` directory, and place the following in `main.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "example/utils"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    answer := utils.Add(1, 2, 3)
    fmt.Printf("got answer: %d\n", answer)
}
```

So that I have the follow layout:

```
$ tree .
.
├── example
├── go.mod
├── main.go
└── utils
    ├── add_test.go
    └── math.go
```

Your code compiles with a problem:

```
$ go build
```

And I run the resulting binary:

```
$ ./example
Current Number: 1
Current Number: 2
Current Number: 3
got answer: 6
```

I would like to point out that I haven't set `GOPATH` or any other `GO*` environment variables for this to work.

Comment: I deleted the go.mod and re ran the go mod init command, and now its running correctly. This happens with node modules, i didn't knew this happened with go too. Thank your answer clear more things for me.